# Who was that masked flagger?

Tags: discussion, spam

I have noticed a constant stream of spam flags applied to old answers and questions, lately. Someone or more is apparently spending a good deal of time combing the site for old, bad stuff.

I've had my obsessional moments, but this seems over and above the call of duty. Perhaps we need a badge for this? Or perhaps someone would care to take a bow?

Comment: I guess I've flagged a few old posts, but only because I found them through google. I guess other users do that as well. So maybe it's not from a single user, but from increased page rank or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's only three flags over there right now, and all of them have been flagged by at least one other user.

Flags are meant to be anonymous, and it should stay that way.  I've only ever taken people to task over flags when a group of high-rep users abuses them to forcibly delete a question they don't like.

Comment: Yes, but at least one is on an antique, and over the last few weeks there have been lots more. I don't care who flagged 'post x', I was curious about the insomnia level that goes into flagging spam from 2008.

Comment: Antique or not, questions and answers do not disappear from google or the search option. If someone is looking for help and finds the question has been answered, who cares if the answer was written in the stone age if the person gets the help they need. And if they see something that needs flagging while they are looking, then flag it. The date stuff was posted is the LAST thing I look at if I ever look at it at all.